# OpenAM would not redirect to HTTPS but worked with HTTP

Tags: https, openam

I have a question about the OpenAM, I facing the problem that the OpenAM cannot redirect my web page to HTTPS, but when we redirect to HTTP, it worked fine.. it get the error of 500-internal error.

Thanks alot for the help :)

Comment: Could you post the logs at https://gist.github.com/?

Comment: Do you really mean OpenAM can not redirect or do you mean OpenAM Agent can not redirect?

Be aware that by default Agents probe the configured login/ CDC Servlet URL ... so if this has 'https' scheme proper trust must be established